The best data-model to store nested tags?
I'm trying to make a breadcrumb for a ecommerce website. Something like this:
Home > Kitchen > Serving and reception > Spoon 

Each of those item are a tag. So, the tags table is parent-based/historical. Here is a sample of the table structure:
// tags
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| id |         name          | parent_id |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+
| 1  | Home                  | Null      |
| 2  | Kitchen               | 1         |
| 3  | Serving and reception | 2         |
| 4  | Spoon                 | 3         |
| 5  | Digital               | NULL      |
| 6  | Communication         | 5         |
| 7  | Cellphone             | 6         |
| .. | ...                   | ...       |
+----+-----------------------+-----------+

In this case, it's very hard to fetch all nested-relate-items in a correct order. Should I change the database structure? I mean, what's the best approach to have such a data model?

Noted that, currently I use a PHP-loop to fetch the related tags and make that breadcrumb. Also, I use MySQL ver 8.0.37.

There are several queries I could think of: get all descendants of a given id (in preorder, in postorder, in BFS/level order), get all children of a given id, get all ancestors of a given id (top to bottom, bottom to top), get all siblings of a given id, ...etc, ...Etc. Which are you asking about? Have you considered recursive queries?

Here's an example of a recursive query that also keeps track of rank if it is any help. For your case, I think you'd need to work "bottom up", since I'm assuming one parent can have many children.

@trincot Thanks for your explanations. You know, my primary issue that I'm clueless about, is how should I connect these tags to a product. Should I keep product_id in which record of tags table to be able access the product by each of related layer? I want to fetch all cellphones (products) by each of Digital, Communication, Cellphone tags. So, how should I connect products and tags  table to each other? Do I need a pivot?

The products table record should link (with foreign key) to the deepest tag it belongs to, as the higher level tags follow from that (via the parent_id).

You can use recursive CTE like this:
WITH RECURSIVE TagHierarchy AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent_id, name AS path
    FROM tags
    WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id, t.name, t.parent_id,
          CONCAT(th.path, ' > ', t.name) AS path
    FROM tags t
    JOIN TagHierarchy th ON t.parent_id = th.id
)
SELECT id, name, path
FROM TagHierarchy
ORDER BY path;

Result
+----+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| id | name                  | path                             |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Home                  | Home                             |
|  2 | Kitchen               | Home > Kitchen                   |
|  3 | Serving and reception | Home > Kitchen > Serving and reception |
|  4 | Spoon                 | Home > Kitchen > Serving and reception > Spoon |
|  5 | Digital               | Digital                          |
|  6 | Communication         | Digital > Communication          |
|  7 | Cellphone             | Digital > Communication > Cellphone |
+----+-----------------------+----------------------------------+


Are there are two alliance? parent_id name AS path
